# Adobe AEM - Use ReactJS Components in Non SPA website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, adobe, aem

I have a simple multilingual multi page website build using Adobe AEM 6.5, HTML, CSS, Javascript and Jquery.

In this website we have multiple links in header, on click of specific link html page is rendered and each html page is built using multiple Web Components and content is author-able.

I have a requirement in the same website, where I need to load page built with ReactJS components. I have react code ready, but how can I integrate with AEM project.

Can anyone please help with reference links for the same?

I am new to AEM, all references which I got are related to including ReactJS components in SPA app, but my case is specific Non SPA.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need authoring capabilities or only to have the current page to be loaded inside AEM?

Comment: @ronnyfm Need authoring capabilities too.